# Rails Mongoid search with many-to-many where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I have "Vaga":

**vaga.rb**

```
class Vaga
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_and_belongs_to_many :areas, autosave: true
```

As a result:

```
#<Vaga _id: 5524940d706f6c09180c0000, area_ids: [BSON::ObjectId('5524939b706f6c09180b0000'), BSON::ObjectId('5436721b706f6c0918cf0000')], titulo: "Ruby on Rails developer">
```

And "Area"
**area.rb**

```
class Area
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_and_belongs_to_many :vagas
```

How can I get all the "vagas" with an array of "areas"?

I'm trying this:

```
vagas = Vaga.all('areas.id' => '5524939b706f6c09180b0000')
```

But it won't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
vagas = Vaga.where(area_ids: ['5524939b706f6c09180b0000'])
```

**or**

```
area = Area.where(id: '5524939b706f6c09180b0000').first
vagas = area.vagas
```

Hope this help!